# View detailed information in PHP page when user click "view link" in data table

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have the following code where it fetch and display a data table from database..and next to each user i have "View" link where it display a detailed information page.

```
if ($role == 'Manager' && isset($_GET['click'])){
 if ($_GET['click'] == 'ViewRequests'){
  $sql="SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.middle_name, users.last_name, request.emp_id, request.location, request.asset_kind, request.Status
  FROM users
  INNER JOIN request ON users.user_id=request.emp_id AND users.role IN ('Employee','Admin') AND request.Status='Request';";
  $records=mysql_query($sql);
  ViewRequest($records); 
  }}                                                                    
     function ViewRequest($records){
       echo "<table width='600' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' style='top:-150px;'>
<h1 align='center'>View Requests</h1>
<tr><th>User id</th><th>Employee Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Asset Kind</th><th>Status</th><th>    </th></tr>";
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['first_name']."    ".$row['middle_name']."    ".$row['last_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['asset_kind']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='view.php'>VIEW</a></td>";       
    }echo "</tr>";}echo "</table>";
```

when the user clicks on "View" link it should display a specific information for each user. How could i implement this in PHP?.. I know that i have to use SESSION but how? should i pass the query or new variables or what?

Comment: You must use GET variables like this in your href link : `view.php?id=1`,`view.php?id=2` ...
This is an example.

Comment: Why not pass user id as query param?
`echo "<td> <a href='view.php?user_id=".$row['user_id'].">VIEW</a></td>";`

Comment: Simplest way would be to pass the user ID in the link to view.php `<a href="view.php?userid=" . $row['user_id'] . ">

Answer (score 1):

If your user id is unique, then you could pass it as a parameter:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['first_name']."    ".$row['middle_name']."    ".$row['last_name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['asset_kind']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Status']."</td>";
  echo "<td> <a href='view.php?user_id=". $row['user_id']."'>VIEW</a></td>";       
}
```

And then in `view.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['user_id']) $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
```